# How to get which result satisfy from confusion matrix prediction

Tags: r, decision-tree

I did a decision tree model to predict the MVP from an NBA player dataset. The outcome of the confusion matrix indicates that it has three right predictions, so I wonder is it anyway for me to find out which three players from my dataset?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you constructed the confusion matrix I am sure you have the test labels already. Simply find the indices of the test labels that correspond to the MVP class. Use these indices in your test data to find the names of the players. Your code should look like this:

```
index<-which(test_label==1, arr.ind = TRUE) # assuming 1 is the class label for MVP
for iter in 1:dim(index)[1]{
print(test_data[index[iter],])
}
```